# Not allow an input field to contain only whitespace and special characters

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-validation

So I want to validate that my input field contains not just whitespace (spacebar) and special characters. I made a directive for whitespace here:

```js
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS, Validator, ValidationErrors, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[noWhiteSpace]', 
  providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: NoWhitespaceDirective, multi: true }]
})
export class NoWhitespaceDirective implements Validator {

  constructor() { }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
    if(!control.value || control.value.trim() == '')
    {
      return {'required' : true };
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

I'm still figuring out the validation for the special characters. Hope to find some solution here.

Comment: I would try `/^[\p{L}\s]+$/.test(myUserInput)` check, where `\p{L}` matches a single Unicode code-point in the category "letter", **but** JavaScript does not seem to support Regular-Expression fully yet (2022).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the special characters in Regex.

> ., +, *, ?, ^, $, (, ), [, ], {, }, |, \

Reference: [Regular Expression Tutorial (Regex Syntax Summary section)](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html#:%7E:text=Special%20Regex%20Characters%3A%20These%20characters,E.g.%2C%20%5C.)

**Updated**

While you can use the regex pattern below to validate the **input with all its character(s) are special character**:

```
^[^\w\s]+$
```

Match all characters other than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and whitespace from beginning to end.

[Demo @ Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/3dBwSp/1)

---

In a directive way,

```js
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  ValidationErrors,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[noSpecialCharactersOnly]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      useExisting: NoSpecialCharacterOnlyDirective,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class NoSpecialCharacterOnlyDirective {
  constructor() {}

  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
    if (/^[^\w\s]+$/.exec(control.value)) {
      return { specialCharactersOnly: true };
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lwqn6c?file=src/app/no-special-character.directive.ts)

Comment: I tried the directive you provided and it seems to not allow any special characters in the text field. What I am looking for is a directive(or any method) where the text field allow special characters but not only special characters. for example, if the text field has an input like '!>*?' then the validation is invalid. If the text field has input like '!#?Apple Inc', then it is valid.

Comment: Done update my answer. Sorry misunderstood the question.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I applied the directive you suggested and it worked perfectly! Thanks alot man really appreciate it =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `validators.pattern('regex')` in formcontrol itself so that it will work fine.

Here regex is for validation special characters